# why application context cannot be loaded?

Tags: spring-mvc, maven-3, junit4

can any body explain why should i getting the following error message "Failed to load ApplicationContext" while testing my test cases

```
 mvn test
```

Comment: We need to see your test class and configuration.

Comment: read the stacktrace, you should get a hint there of what's going on. it could be anything that spring would trip over when reading the appcontext xml, like invalid xml, or a class specified that isn't found, or invalid properties specified on a bean.

Answer (score 2):

If your using the Spring framework, you can specify the location of your applicationContext.xml file using the @ContextConfiguration annotation:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/path/to/your/applicationContext.xml" })
public class MyTest {

}
```

Comment: even though configuring @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/src/test/resources/applicationContext.xml" }) my problem doesnot resolved

Comment: also same kind of the error "application context.xml"cannot be loaded

Answer (score 1):

Check your @ContextConfiguration. Quote from the [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-xml):

> A plain or relative path — for example "context.xml" — will be treated
>   as a classpath resource that is relative to the package in which the
>   test class is defined. A path starting with a slash is treated as an
>   absolute classpath location, for example "/org/example/config.xml". A
>   path which represents a resource URL (i.e., a path prefixed with
>   classpath:, file:, http:, etc.) will be used as is.

So I suppose you have to use "`/applicationContext.xml`" instead of "`/src/test/resources/applicationContext.xml`" as the file will be placed at the root level in your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't see your configuration you could just change your Test to use the following class level annotations.  This should help find the application context as long as it is in the classpath.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({ "classpath:applicationContext.xml" })
```